# Eclipse Plug-in:How can we show/hide a particular wizard entry based on certain conditions?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, wizard

I have a custom wizard entry in File->New->Other->Web->MyEntry.

I want this entry to show up only on

1)selection of particular project type(as in when I do a right click on that Project->New->Other->Web->MyEntry or when that particular project is selected.

2)Some particular folder in that projec type is selected

I am able to get my project type and also able to validate the folder which is associated with the project type. Earlier, I used property tester to get my work done for a similar situation for a context menu. Do we need to use a property tester or is there any other specific way which has to be used inside a `<wizard>` tag.

```
 <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.newWizards">
 <category
        name="%CategoryName"
        id="com.sample.webtemplate">
  </category>
 <wizard
            name="%WebWizard"
            icon="icons/newhtml_wiz.gif"
            category="org.eclipse.wst.web.ui"
            class="com.abc.webtemplate.wizards.WebWizard"
            project="false"
            id="com.abc.webtemplate.wizards.WebWizard">
           <description>%WebWizardDesc</description>
      </wizard>
     </extension>
```

Comment: Tried using the  <visibleWhen>
           <with variable="selection">
             <instanceof value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject"/>
                    <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature" 
                         value="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature"/>
       </with>                  
            </visibleWhen> but doesn't work inside the <wizard></wizard> tag

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, you do this with expression-based activities. See the [help](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_advext_activities.htm) for information on how to setup these. You might also find a little help in an old [blog post](http://tonnymadsen.blogspot.com/2007/06/using-activities-for-user-management.html) of mine :-)

**UPDATED** the link

Answer (score 0):

Use the [commonWizard declaration](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_navigator_navigatorContent.html&anchor=e.commonWizard) of the navigatorContent extension point. CDT uses this to hide the "New C file" wizards as long as you have not yet created a C project.